# Do singular values dominate eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ complex matrix with singular values $s_1 \ge s_2 \ge \cdots \ge s_n$ and eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ arranged so that  $|\lambda_1| \ge |\lambda_2| \ge \cdots \ge |\lambda_n|$. Is it true that $s_1 \ge |\lambda_1|,\ s_1+s_2 \ge |\lambda_1| + |\lambda_2|,$ and so on?

Comment: For normal matrices, it seems clear that we have the even stronger statement $s_j \ge \lambda_j$ for each $j$.  On the other hand, for non-normal matrices this stronger statement fails.

Comment: @David: How does this correlate with $\prod s_i=\prod |\lambda_i|=|\det A|$?

Comment: Am I missing something, or for normal matrices $s_i=|\lambda_i|$, since the eigendecomposition is an SVD up to phase factors?

Comment: @Federico: Surely;)

Comment: A relevant reference here is the classic paper of Horn, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=61573 , showing that the Weyl inequalities in Yanqi's answer in fact generate the complete set of relations between singular values and eigenvalues.  Also, one can prove the inequalities by applying Gram-Schmidt to the eigenvectors to conjugate $A$ by a unitary matrices to upper-triangular form (so that the eigenvalues become diagonal entries), and then applying the SVD and orthogonality relations for the singular vectors.

Answer (score 11):

Let $\lambda(A)$ denote the vector of eigenvalues and $s(A)$ the vector of singular values (arranged in decreasing order). The claim of the question is whether $|\lambda(A)|^{\downarrow} \prec_w s(A)$. The answer to this question is **yes** (the proof follows using the tensor power trick **Yanqi Qui** mentioned above).

> **Theorem** (Weyl's Majorant theorem). Let $f: (0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be such that $f(e^t)$ is convex and monotone increasing in $t$. Then
>   $$[f(\vert\lambda_1\vert),\ldots, f(|\lambda_n|)] \prec_w [f(s_1),\ldots,f(s_n)].$$

As a corollary, using the function $t \mapsto t^p$ for any $p \ge 0$, we obtain **an affirmative answer to the OP's question** (actually, by merely using the special case $p=1$). Actually, Weyl's Majorant theorem provides the following [log-majorization](http://books.google.com/books?id=I9wfajyOrooC&lpg=PA16&dq=log%20majorization&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q=log%20majorization&f=false) (which implies the above result):
\begin{equation*}
   \log |\lambda(A)| \prec \log s(A),
\end{equation*}
and this version also answers Ilya's comment, namely $\prod_i^n |\lambda_i| = \prod_i^n s_i$.

Another closely related result is that of absolute values of the Hermitian part of a complex matrix. Let $\Re(A) := (A+A^*)/2$. Then, we have

> **Theorem** (Fan-Hoffman). For every matrix $A$, we have
>   \begin{eqnarray*}
>    \lambda_j^{\downarrow}(\Re(A)) &\le& s_j(A),\qquad 1\le j \le n\\
>    |\lambda(\Re(A))| &\prec_w& s(A).
> \end{eqnarray*}

**Reference**

[R. Bhatia, Matrix Analysis](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-387-94846-1) (Springer GTM, 169).

Answer (score 7):

The singular values of $A$ are the eigenvalues of $|A|$. Since $$ \lambda_1(A) \lambda_2(A) \cdots \lambda_k(A)$$ is an eigenvalue of $\underbrace{A\wedge A\wedge \dots \wedge A }_{\text{$k$ times}} $,  we have \begin{align*} |\lambda_1(A) \lambda_2(A) \cdots \lambda_k(A) | & \le \| A\wedge A\wedge \dots \wedge A \| \\ &= \Big\| \left|A\wedge A\wedge \dots \wedge A\right| \Big\| \\ & = \Big\| |A|\wedge |A|\wedge \dots \wedge |A| \Big\| \\ & = \lambda_1(|A|) \lambda_2(|A|) \cdots \lambda_k(|A|) .\end{align*} It follows that $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \varphi(|\lambda_k(A)|) \le \sum_{k=1}^n\varphi(\lambda_k(|A|)) ,$$ for any $\varphi$ such that $t \rightarrow \varphi(e^t)$ is convex non-decreasing.

Comment: I realize I didn't really answer the original question. Sorry.

Comment: Actually your answer does answer the original question, by creating weak majorization inequalities for the entire range, rather than just the $k=1,..,n$ case.