# An inequality on elementary symmetric polynomial of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, eigenvalues, symmetric-functions

For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, I am wondering if the following inequality holds,
$$\text{tr}(A)^2 - \text{tr}(A^2) \leq ||A||_*^2 - ||A||_F^2$$
This is equivalent to the following inequality on the elementary symmetric polynomial,
$$\sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_j \leq \sum_{i<j} \sigma_i \sigma_j$$
where $\lambda_i$ and $\sigma_i$ denote the eigenvalues and singular values of $A$.

This question arises originally from a discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117111/bounding-the-coefficients-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-matrix).
I am still looking for a proof or counterexample to this inequality.

Comment: Are you assuming $A$ to have positive, or at least real eigenvalues?

Comment: @darijgrinberg No. $A$ is any real valued square matrix.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that the symmetric polynomials are real anyway :)

Comment: I think your inequality is just the inequality from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381808/sum-of-eigenvalues-and-singular-values , but applied to the compound matrix $\wedge^2 A$ (of size $\dbinom{n}{2} \times \dbinom{n}{2}$) instead of $A$. Can you check?

Comment: What is $\|A\|_*$ ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling It is the nuclear norm (sum of singular values) of A.

Comment: Feels like this should follow from the standard inequalities between ev's and singular values such as these: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185412/do-singular-values-dominate-eigenvalues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Darij in the comments to the OP, the compound matrix $\wedge^2 A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i \lambda_j$ and singular values $\sigma_i \sigma_j$. This result can be found, for example in Theorem 2.16 of

*Zhan, Xingzhi*, Matrix theory, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 147. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-0-8218-9491-0/hbk). x, 253 p. (2013). [ZBL1275.15001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1275.15001).

[see also](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/gsm-147). Applying the inequality from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381808/sum-of-eigenvalues-and-singular-values) proves the desired inequality.